# Write one query instead of four queries

Tags: elasticsearch

Dears,

I have a problem with write my proper complex query. I try to write one query which will do the same what other four queries which should:
count docs which have codes 1?? or 2?? in field ci.rc
and
count docs which have codes 9?? in field ci.rc
and
count docs which have codes 0?? in field ci.rc and have codes 1210 or 1230 in field ci.mti
and
count docs which have codes 1400 or 1420 in field ci.mti

Could you advice me how to write one query which will do the same what four separate queries, please? Any advice? Please.

My skeleton of one query:

```
GET /log-2020.07.08/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "ci.rc",
            "query": "(1??) or (2??)"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "ci.rc",
            "query": "(9??)"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "regexp": {
                  "ci.rc": "0[0-9]{2}"
                }
              },
              {
                "regexp": {
                  "ci.mti": "[0-9]{2}[3|5|7|9][0-9]{1}"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "rc": {
        "terms": {"field": "ci.rc.keyword","size": 10}
      }
    }
  }
```

There is missing date condition and last separate query:
count docs which have codes 1400 or 1420 in field ci.mti

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Your query handles all four conditions. What is missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query string query is meant for these use cases only. In query string query you can write each and every query in a string format

Here can be the refined query

```
GET /log-2020.07.08/_search?size=0

{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(ci.rc:((1??) or (2??) or (9??))) and (ci.rc:/0[0-9]{2}/) and ci.mti:/[0-9]{2}[3|5|7|9][0-9]{1}/"
    }
  }
}
```

Also here is a link having syntax for putting almost each type of query in query string

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html